# Login and Registration on the index page using django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-registration

I am using `django-allauth`. I want the login and signup forms both on the home page of my website and not on '/accounts/login' or '/accounts/signup'

I have created a separate app. The following code is in `views.py`

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm


class CustomSignupView(SignupView):
    # here we add some context to the already existing context
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # we get context data from original view
        context = super(CustomSignupView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['login_form'] = LoginForm()  # add form to context
        return context
```

the following is in `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<button id="toggleForms">Toggle Forms</button>

<form method='post' action='/accounts/signup/' id='signup'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>blah</h1>
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Sign Up'>
</form>

<form method='post' action='/accounts/login/' id='login'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login_form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Log In'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The forms work when the inputs are correct i.e. the form is valid. The problem is when the validation fails (in case of incorrect credential) the user is redirected to accounts/login and the error message is displayed. How to stop this redirect and show the error messages too on the home page?

Comment: The view isn't redirecting when the login is invalid - you are posting the login details to a different url with `action='/accounts/login/'`.  Returning the user to the page that they submitted the form from is tricky. It will require changing the login view and the signup view. It might be a better approach would be to submit the login details as an Ajax request if you really don't want the errors to be shown on the login page.

Comment: Can oauth logins be also done using ajax? If yes, then how?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is possible, it might be tricky to implement.

Comment: So may be I'm stuck to  the default urls?

Comment: I think that what you are trying to do is possible, but it will require lots of customization of allauth and may not be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to override the template so that it looks like your index page. You can either specify a template with the name ('account/login.html'), or specify your own version of the URL, with a different template altogether:

```
from allauth.account.views import LoginView

...
    url(r'^my-login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="my-login"),
...
```

Neither of these are part of the public API for allauth, so use them at your own risk...

Comment: Yes I can override the template and use it at a different url, but what I want is to show the login and signup on the same page. I don't think I can do that without touching the views?