# Allauth login form Django base template with popup

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am trying to create a login and/or signup popup on my django pages in a bootstrap modal.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166055/show-a-form-in-my-template-base-using-django) answer to create a Context Processor returning the allauth login form and the redirecting the action of this form to 'accounts/login/'

```
<form method='post' action='/accounts/login/' id='login'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login_form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Log In'>
</form>
```

With the context proccessor

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm
def login_form(request):
return {
    'login_form': LoginForm
}
```

This works pretty well i can login and logout again using a button going to accounts/logout.

Until i enter I wrong user, instead of showing me the error in the modal on my home page it goes to accounts/login and shows the error there (which is kind of expected). I figure I would need to render the view im going to inside the modal, similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499449/django-allauth-login-signup-form-on-homepage).

What would be the best practice here?

Edit: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925528/login-and-registration-on-the-index-page-using-django-allauth?rq=1) question, and its also not answered. It seems like django allauth is not the right tool for this kind of behaviour.

Since its generally a well known workflow (having logins in between of actions), is there any other apps for django that provide this functionality? There is also django-registration-redux, is that more powerful?

Regards
Julian

Comment: Hey, @Julian Did you find answer of this question ?